# How to attach conditionals to eloquent relation query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to create the filters and I just want to attach the query to relation by using some conditionals. I don't want to put those conditional in the first block of the code. So how can I get the query instance so I can attach the new queries to the existing relation?

```
    $query = Category::query();

    $query->where('category_type', 'xyz')
        ->with(['products' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('condition1', 'value')
                ->where('condition2', 'value');
        }]);


    if (isset($queryParams['param1'])) {
        $query->with(['products' => function ($query) use ($queryParams) {
            $query->getQuery()->where('type', $queryParams['param1']);
        }]);
    }
```

Currently, it just overwrites the first query relation condition.

Comment: Why don't you make the condition in the first function itself.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit That works. But I wanted instance so I can attach the way I want without putting things in the first function.

Comment: you are attaching a closure that's why it just replaced every time.

Comment: Or also use the whereHas if you want to make conditions on the relationships.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit I'm not sure how can I attach the conditions to the first relation out of that function. The example I posted above is the tinkering I was doing.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit I want to load the data of products so I don't think whereHas will work because whereHas just applies a condition for parent table.

Comment: Yes I thought you want the specific categories data based on the product that's i have mentioned the wherehas.

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```php
$query = Category::query();

$query->where('category_type', 'xyz')
->with(['products' => function ($query) use ($queryParams) {
    $query->where('condition1', 'value')
    ->where('condition2', 'value');
    if (isset($queryParams['param1'])) {
        $query->where('type', $queryParams['param1']);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: That works. But I wanted instance so I can attach the way I want without putting things in the first function.

Comment: So for that, you need to `clone` the `$query` object after the first function.

Comment: I'll check on that and will reply here